# Font is thinned out at the edges when using @font-face

Tags: css

When I am adding a font to my website via a google fonts  tag, my font displays fine. But when I add it as a file via @font-face, it gets thinned out.

Example:[image]

Here's the code that I use:

```
.title {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'myBodoni', serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 200px;
    font-size: 64px;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: normal;
}
.img {
    position: relative;
    margin: 3%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myBodoni;
  src: url(bodoni-variable.ttf); //variable file downloaded directly from google fonts
}
```

When I add this code, it works properly:

Css:

```
font-family: 'Bodoni Moda', serif;
```

Html

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bodoni+Moda&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here's how it looks with the following code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are only adding one `@font-type`. You need to add `@font-type` for `eot`, `woff2`, `woff` & `svg`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```